# says syntax error on token "int", delete this token

Tags: java, android

in line   "int k = 2 * AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(paramInt1, i, j);" gives me title error which i typedi dont know why gives me this error , what is wrong ? (my ide = eclipse )

```
public class EmuMedia
{
private static SurfaceHolder holder;
private static Emulator.OnFrameDrawnListener onFrameDrawnListener;
private static Rect region = new Rect();
private static AudioTrack track;
private static float volume = AudioTrack.getMaxVolume();

static boolean audioCreate(int paramInt1, int paramInt2, int paramInt3)
{
  int i = 3;
  int j;
  if (paramInt2 == 16)
  {
    j = 2;
    if (paramInt3 != 2) {
      break label61;
    }
  }
  for (;;)
  {
    if ((track == null) || (track.getSampleRate() != paramInt1) ||     (track.getAudioFormat() != j) || (track.getChannelCount() != paramInt3)) {
      break label66;
    }
    return true;
    j = i;
    break;
    label61:
    i = 2;
  }
  label66:
   int k = 2 * AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(paramInt1, i, j);
  if (k < 1500) {
    k = 1500;
  }
  try
  {
    track = new AudioTrack(3, paramInt1, i, j, k, 1);
    if (track.getState() == 0) {
      track = null;
    }
    if (track == null) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  catch (IllegalArgumentException localIllegalArgumentException)
  {
    for (;;)
    {
      track = null;
    }
    track.setStereoVolume(volume, volume);
  }
  return true;
}

static void audioDestroy()
{
  if (track != null)
  {
    track.stop();
    track = null;
  }
}

static void audioPause()
{
  if (track != null) {
    track.pause();
  }
}

static void audioPlay(byte[] paramArrayOfByte, int paramInt)
{
  if (track != null) {
    track.write(paramArrayOfByte, 0, paramInt);
  }
}

static void audioSetVolume(int paramInt)
{
  float f = AudioTrack.getMinVolume();
  volume = f + (AudioTrack.getMaxVolume() - f) * paramInt / 100.0F;
  if (track != null) {
    track.setStereoVolume(volume, volume);
  }
}

static void audioStart()
{
  if (track != null) {
    track.play();
  }
}

static void audioStop()
{
  if (track != null)
  {
    track.stop();
    track.flush();
  }
}

static void bitBlt(int[] paramArrayOfInt, boolean paramBoolean)
{
  Canvas localCanvas = holder.lockCanvas();
  localCanvas.drawColor(-16777216);
  if (paramBoolean) {
      localCanvas.rotate(180.0F, localCanvas.getWidth() / 2,     localCanvas.getHeight() / 2);
  }
  localCanvas.drawBitmap(paramArrayOfInt, 0, region.width(),   region.left, region.top, region.width(), region.height(), false, null);
  if (onFrameDrawnListener != null) {
    onFrameDrawnListener.onFrameDrawn(localCanvas);
  }
  holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(localCanvas);
}

static void destroy()
{
  if (track != null)
  {
    track.stop();
    track = null;
  }
}

public static void setOnFrameDrawnListener(Emulator.OnFrameDrawnListener     paramOnFrameDrawnListener)
{
  onFrameDrawnListener = paramOnFrameDrawnListener;
}

static void setSurface(SurfaceHolder paramSurfaceHolder)
{
  holder = paramSurfaceHolder;
}

static void setSurfaceRegion(int paramInt1, int paramInt2, int   paramInt3, int paramInt4)
{
  region.set(paramInt1, paramInt2, paramInt1 + paramInt3, paramInt2 +   paramInt4);
}
}
```

can any body help me ? special thanks for aid

Comment: Only loops can have labels - it doesn't make sense to break out of a variable declaration.

Comment: First off, restructure your code to avoid labels. You're using them as completely unreadable `goto`s and managed to spaghettify Java. Then, if at all possible, replace your `int` parameters with sensible enums.

Comment: I hope this code sample if some kind of bad taste joke.  Your code is unreadable, beyond repair.

Comment: You can't use break as goto in Java. You always must be inside the loop you are breaking out of, even when it is a labeled loop.

Comment: Funnily enough you can just remove label66 and do a normal break out of that for loop. However, that's not the only problem in your code...

Comment: Please forgive me for being honest, but your code is awful.  There are so many problems that it would take pages to go over them.  Your best advice is to complete some basic OOP and Java tutorials, then coming back to build apps.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because unfortunately, the question is beyond saving.

Comment: @Simon it becuse code seems to be taken from some decompiler....

Comment: @Selvin Ah, good point.  In that case, voting to close for attempting to steal someone else's property!

Comment: @Selvin  Funny thing is, this class is on Github ;)

Comment: ... Hehe without labels :-)

Comment: i didn't write this code , i have generated this code using dex2jar tool , and i have some problems with this code, does any body know that dex2jar can change source code ? application that i extract this code runs normaly always but this codes i see cant run , what's wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

You can put a label on an arbitrary statement. Therefore `int k; label: k = 0;` is perfectly legal java. However `label: int k = 0;` does not compile as a declaration does not count as a statement. However, you really should only use labels on loop statements, and even then only on rare occasions (such as breaking out of nested loops). You certainly should not use labels as a way of getting round the fact that `goto` is not supported.

Comment: I have to say I was intrigued by this answer and did some research/testing. You can indeed define a label on any statement, and your comment about the declaration is correct too. But you can only break to a label from inside a loop if it is defined _on_ the loop statement itself, not after, or further before the loop. You can also do nothing with a label on an arbitrary statement, except define it. However, you can do a labeled break _anywhere_ in your code (even outside a loop or switch), as long as the label is _on_ the break statement, which again, does nothing. Hilarious.

Comment: @ci_ I never said there was any point putting a label on an arbitrary statement! I guess they only allowed it to make the language easier to define (?). I can see there may be a point of putting a label on a `switch` (so that you can `break` from a case from within a `for` loop), although I have never seen that done. I only answered this question because people were saying in comments that only loops can have labels. The label issue is only one of many problems with that terrible code.

Comment: completely agree, I wasn't criticizing your answer. Just wanted to highlight the bizarre-ness of that you can do this in Java, which I never knew. You can even have `out: break out;` anywhere in your code, which of course does nothing, but again, the usual thinking is "you can only have a break inside a loop or switch", which seems to be wrong.

Comment: @ci_ I didn't know you could write `out: break out;`. That's brilliant. Another interesting thing is that a block counts as a statement, so you can write `label: { // code if (condition) break label; // code }`. This enables you to do a forward `goto`. Nobody should ever do that though!

Comment: Just had the same thought. Makes sense I suppose. You can break out of any statement as long as the label is on the statement. A block is a statement, a loop/switch is a statement. Any non-block/non-loop/non-switch statement, can only be a single break itself, or the label is unused. You learn something new every day, turns out this question was good for something.

Comment: i have this code using a decompiler , can trust to decompilers really ? it have given me this problemitive code

Comment: @BehnamRanjbar I looks like you can't trust this one. I don't know how it managed to produce `for (;;) { track = null; }`.